# How to validate a request with nested json objects in django rest framework using serializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have following request.

```
{
  "customer_details": {
    "id": 6, // either id or below fields should be present to create new customer in database
    "name": "Name",
    "email": "email@example.com",
    "mobile": "1234567890",
    "company": "Company Name" // not mandatoy
  },
  "delivery_address": {
    "id": 7, // either id or below fields should be present to create new address in database
    "title": "Delivery Address Title 1",
    "street": "Delivery Address Street 1",
    "suite": "Delivery Address suite 1", // not mandatoy
    "city": "Delivery Address city 1",
    "zipcode": "zipcode1",
    "county": "Dade",
    "state": "Delivery Address state 1"
  },
  "billing_address": {
    "id": 8, // either id or below fields should be present to create new address in database
    "title": "Billing Address Title 1",
    "street": "Billing Address Street 1",
    "suite": "Billing Address suite 1", // not mandatoy
    "city": "Billing Address city 1",
    "zipcode": "zipcode2",
    "county": "Billing Address county 1",
    "state": "Billing Address state 1",
    "payment_method": "Cheque"
  }
}
```

How can I validate the above request using django serializers?

Answer (score 0):

Using nested Serializers should work!

```
class DataSerializer:
    customer_details = CustomerDetailSerializer
    delivery_address = DeliveryAddressSerializer
    billing_address = BillingAddressSerializer
```

and then define each serializer with the correct data.

Comment: how should I validate either id or below fields condition in the serializers?